# Pass config file to docker container at creation time without bind-mout

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have an application composed of several containers that are created through a docker-compose file.

Some of those are standards containers from the docker hub.
In order to get one of them to interconnect properly, I have to get itto use a predefined config file instead of it's default one.

One way to achieve this would be to bind-mout the config file from the host to the container, but since this custom config is always the same and should not be changed by the user, I don't really like the idea of having it exposed on the host.

Is there any way to put the file inside the container at creation time, without mouting a host folder ?

NB : the container image doesn't supports enough parameters through ENV variables to fully customize the conf file.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a derived Docker image `FROM` any image you'd like.  By default it will inherit everything from its base image.  In that image, you can `COPY` additional files in and make other changes.  For example:

```sh
FROM postgres:13
COPY postgresql.conf /etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf
```

In a Compose-based setup, you can `build:` this like any other image

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  postgres:
    build: .
    ports: ['5432:5432']
    volumes: ['pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data']
volumes:
  pgdata:
```

If you're distributing this setup more broadly, you can also include an `image:` in the Compose setup pointing to your private Docker Hub space or another repository, and `docker-compose push` the image with the updated config file.

This is subject to the usual caveats on derived images.  You can't change files in a directory the base image declares as a `VOLUME` (and correspondingly can't create a database image with pre-seeded data).  You can't force runtime-only options like volume mounts or published ports.  If you have reason to reset `ENTRYPOINT` in your derived image, it also resets `CMD`.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with @David Maze -- creating a new image based on the original is the best route.

To give another option, you could download the configuration file during application startup by overriding the `command` in your docker-compose.yml to download the configuration file from somewhere on the internet at startup (you have to host the file somewhere, could be a github gist, s3 bucket, az blob, etc...).

```
# Assuming wget is installed
command: bash -c "wget https://some.domain/myfile.txt -O /some/path/config.txt && execute-your-application"
```

Comment: The workaround you suggest could do the trick, but modifiyng the command won't mess with the defined entrypoint ?

Comment: It won't mess with the `ENTRYPOINT` (if there is one) but it will override the `CMD` so you would likely need to execute the desired commands as part of your `command` section.  Depends how the image is built.